# connect View to ViewModel with DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

I'm trying to understand. When I'm connecting View to ViewModel like this:

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyViewModel}">
        <local:MyView />
    </DataTemplate>
```

What does it mean?

It looks like the View is set to be the DataTemplate of the ViewModel. BUT the ViewModel doesn't have a Property of DataTemplate. So what exactly is going on in there?

A demonstration of the question - How do I do that by code (Connecting the View and ViewModel this specific way. I can't write ViewModel.DataTemplate = View)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

It means "To whatever control whose Content data is MyViewModel place MyView there". You are not setting DataTemplate of viewmodel (That does not mean anything) you are setting the DataTemplate for the control whose Data is MyViewModel.

Comment: The "Content data" of a control means its DataContex?

Comment: No. the content of the control e.g <ContentControl Content="{Binding MyViewModel}"/>.Here i am setting content of control to MyViewModel property in Control's DataContext. So your template will apply here

Comment: I'm not sure I understood. My View is a UserControl, so no control gets the View to be its Content.

Comment: So does this mean that if you instantiate a viewmodel that's has a datatemplate specifying a view, that the view gets displayed with the viewmodel bound to the datacontext?

Answer (score 6):

Take for example an ItemsControl with an Items Source of

```
ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees
```

where each Employee is represented by a DataTemplate for Example :

```
<DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:Employee}">
       <StackPanel>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" />
       </StackPanel> 
</DataTemplate>
```

So in the same manner a MyViewModel.cs such as Employee.cs as a visual representation based on a DataTemplate .

and represented for example as such :

```
 <ContentControl Content="{Binding MyViewModelProperty}" />
```

Comment: The point I don't understand is how is that "visual representation based on a DataTemplate" when the ViewModel has no DataTemplate.  And if speaking about the DataTemplate of that ContentControl, I don't have a ContentControl that its Content is MyViewModel. My View is a control and I don't give it the ViewModel as Content.

Comment: DataTempalte is a visual mapping of logical objects to visual objects , your logical object does not need to contain the way he is represented.

Answer (score 5):

The way how it works is very simple. Your definition of `DataTemplate` is something like a definition of how a data will look like. In your example the data that you want to represent visually are of type:

`DataType="{x:Type local:MyViewModel}"`

By defining `DataTemplate` in control, window or other resources, e.g.

`<UserControl.Resources> ...your template... <UserControl.Resources>`,

you say "Hey, I want that all my data of type `local:MyViewModel` will look like this...". Inside the template you define a root control, that will be put in all places where your `local:MyViewModel` have been used. Normally when you place `local:MyViewModel` in Grid, ContentControl or other containers, you will see its string representation like "xxxx.xxxxx.MyViewModel" instead of visual.

To to see a graphical representation you must define a `DataTemplate`. It will replace the string "xxxx.xxxxx.MyViewModel" - representing your data and put there a visual control you defined in the template. Then when it is done, this representation - control from your `DataTemplate` will get DataContext property set to your View Model, here it will be `local:MyViewModel` instance.

That will give you a possibility to use binding in your DataTemplate, to bind in you DataTemplate directly to properties from you ViewModel.

Is that more clear now?